# Can I send carbon/graphite data to a url on port 80?

Tags: nginx, graphite

I work in an environment where ports are closed and difficult to get open.

I was thinking of sending my graphite data to localhost/graphitein rather than port 2003 and have nginx do the mapping.

Is there any reason not to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia (bold is mine):

> Nginx [...] can also act as a reverse proxy server **for HTTP, HTTPS,
>   SMTP, POP3, and IMAP protocols**, as well as a load balancer and an
>   HTTP cache.

I don't think you can use Nginx as a reverse proxy for the Graphite protocol.

Perhaps you can use an [SSH Tunnel](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html)?

Answer (score 1):

This tool could be a solution https://github.com/obfuscurity/backstop "Backstop is a simple endpoint for submitting metrics to Graphite. It accepts JSON data via HTTP POST and proxies the data to one or more Carbon/Graphite listeners."